# SSIS Execute Package task notification if path does not exist

Tags: ssis

I have created a master control package that calls several packages using the execute package task control. I have set all the package file locations to use a sql config table which contains the file location and then used an expression to include the package name. Everything works as expected however I want to include some handlers to notify me if the package location does not exist (just in case somebody changes the path in the config table). To test I set an incorrect file name in one of the expressions which turned the execute package task control red as expected however I can't figure out how to add the notification task. I have tried all the error handler events assocaited with it but no joy plus I added a mail task to the task in question for failure and this did not execute!

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's why you have `OnError` event handler, just configure it properly. Are you sure, you're checking `Event Handlers` for the package and not for one of the blocks inside?

There's a plenty of system variables with `OnError` scope. Check grey `x` in Variable window to see them. You might want to use:
- ErrorDescription
- ErrorCode
- SourceName
but choose them according to the report format.

Now in event handler create a script which will put a message into a new variable, and finally send it with `send mail task`.

Comment: I probably have not explained very well! The execute package task is contained within a container which is part of the master control package, now the issue is that the task can't find the location so errors saying the file can not be found in execution results tab, however does not fail the master package or container, I have also tried setting the FailPackageOnFailure to true but it doesn't appear to treat it as a failure, if that makes sense.

Comment: Check `MaximumErrorCount` value of your package. Is it larger than 1? Does the task go red?

Comment: The error count is 1 and yes the task does go red, so with this in mind I attached a send mail task to the execute package task and set the Precedence Constraint to failure hower it does not execute!